# Optical receiver output voltage higher than power supply

Tags: digital-logic, ttl, optical-fibre

The part is a [optical receiver](https://www.broadcom.com/products/fiber-optic-modules-components/industrial/industrial-control-general-purpose/650nm/afbr-1629z) from Broadcom. It has TTL output, but specified with a maximum output-high voltage higher than the power supply. I wonder what's special structure internal may make it goes beyond the power supply. As known, it's not good to do this in digital design.

[image]

Comment: Probably saying you can force it there, but don't go higher.

Comment: Well, it can't go very much beyond its supply, just 0.3V. They've probably just calculated/tested that this doesn't cause any problems. It's less than a typical esd diode's turn-on voltage.

Comment: I've tested it, the output goes beyond the power supply indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a low impedance source rated for TTL compatible output, it is easy to get overshoot from reactive probe and ground impedance.  This is no cause for concern.

Measurement errors may be avoided with 10:1 probe tip and ring near output.

Comment: So, you mean the reading measured maybe caused by ringing? Then, what about the specification? It means it can withstand maximum VCCR+0.3? Or it can output maximum VCCR+0.3?

Comment: The spec indicates temporary overshoot is permitted. But I don't know what and how your results were obtained, so I suspect it was classic measurement error. with ringing due to probe inductance.